# a simple line with css doesn't appears sometimes on chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, line, background-color

I don't understand because sometimes a simple color line doesn't appears with Chrome.
My line is defined with CSS code :

```
/* line warning */
.line_warning {
background-color:#ff9900; 
color:white; 
margin-top:5px; 
margin-bottom:5px; 
height: 1px;
}
```

Apparently, I have this problem only with chrome (I use Bootstrap).

Thank you in advance if you have any idea to resolve it.

Comment: Edit your post with a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem and explaining under what conditions it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to create your line with a border rather than a background colour...

```
.line_warning {
height:0px;
    border-top:1px solid #ff9900;
    margin-top:5px; 
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Interested to know if anyone can explain why this is happening, as it seems a issue in Firefox too.

UPDATE: I looked further into this, and found that adding a margin to your body fixes it.

```
body {  
    margin:0px;
}
```

This seems to be what normalize.css use - I have no idea why it works, though.  Seems like a bug.